# mysql_fetch_array returning false when pointer is at exactly 1/2 of mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql

The table is about 1.2M rows (its actively going up, so total rows grows slightly between iterations of this test, but that doesn't change the outcome).

**mysql_num_rows** is displayed - which is accurate, tested with select count(*) - after the pull query in order to show how large the result set is.

Then, a loop assigns the row to an array with **mysql_fetch_array()**.  Iteration counter is incremented for every round, and you would expect it go get to **mysql_num_rows** and then break out of the while loop.  Pretty standard stuff, been done a million times over.

What actually happens, on the other hand, is quite odd.  It gets to exactly 1/2 way (floor(number_of_rows/2)) and then **mysql_fetch_array()** returns false.  No matter how you limit the result set...

```
$iteration = 0;
$result = mysql_query("select `file_id`, `size` from `files`", $dbconn); // get all records
echo "\nDone. Found " . mysql_num_rows($result) . " rows."; // Done. Found 1291595 rows.
if ($result){
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false){
         $iteration++;
    }
    echo "\ngot to $iteration before mysql_fetch_array was false."; // got to 642679 before mysql_fetch_array was false.
}
```

Sometimes $line is an empty array, sometimes mysql_fetch_array triggers false.

It gets mysql_num_rows that i'd expect and continues for 1/2 the records of the total result set size, then it stops...

If I put now, limit = 967356,1000000, I get:

```
Done. Found 324963 rows.
got to 162482 before mysql_fetch_array was false.
```

This is 1 off from being exactly 1/2 way.

limit = 1000000, 1000000:

```
Done. Found 292606 rows.
got to 146303 before mysql_fetch_array was false.
```

What in the world could this be?

php info:

php -v
PHP 5.4.19-1+debphp.org~precise+3 (cli) (built: Aug 27 2013 14:29:42)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [pdo](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) or [mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli).

Comment: where did u initialize `$iteration` ?

Comment: Right before the while loop.  see php info re: depreciated... its still live in php5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid early termination of the while loop in situations where php will interpret the value of `$line` as false, change the line

```
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

to

```
while (($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== FALSE){
```

### Update:

Another possibility is that you're running out of memory on very large result sets. Try using [`mysql_unbuffered_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php) instead of [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

### Another Update:

Yet another possibility is that you have multiple database connections open in this script and `mysql_query()` isn't using the one you think it's using. Pass the optional 2nd argument to be sure. Change

```
mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

to

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, $dbconn)
```

Comment: changed, same effect... with limit 0,20: Done. Found 20 rows.
got to 10 before mysql_fetch_array was false

Comment: @tweak2: Is there more code that you can show. It's possible that your bug lies somewhere else.

Comment: memory wouldn't really make much sense since it's exactly 1/2... if it was memory I would think it would run out at about the same amount of results every time, not exactly half.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I'm pretty dumb.  I had a second $line=mysql_fetch_array($result) in the while loop... causing it to grab 2 rows for every loop.  Appologies.